# Can I somehow replace the "lever" on my PCIe 16x ports?

Tags: pci-express

Can I somehow replace the "lever" on my PCIe 16x ports?

My mobo has the following kinds of ports:

[image]

and I happened to break one of the blue "levers", which made me think, whether these can be replaced to something somehow?

Comment: You would have to replace the entire assembly and it's unlikely you have the soldering skills or the equipment to do so.  The locking mechanism likely works well enough to be used and I speak from experience after doing something similar.  It's there so you can't just pull the card out accidentally

Answer (score 1):

Only if you replace the entire Motherboard.

But these levers are there to ensure a proper fit. If you have a case where you screw the card to the frame, you usually don't need the lever. Try without and see if it all works. The other cards don't have this lever either.

Comment: https://forums.anandtech.com/threads/broke-the-lever-at-the-end-of-pci-express-slot.138304/

Comment: Yeah actually the lever is not required because I can screw the card in the chassis anyways. It's just a cosmetic thing.